# Secure Login with JSP and Websphere

Tags: security, jsp, networking, authentication, websphere

I am designing a secure login with JSP. I intend to use Form Authorization to access an application on a Websphere. The basic idea is that when internal, authenticated users in the domain accesses a page, it will be as per normal. However, should external users try to access it, it will direct them to a login page, interface with Active Directory, and redirect them to the page upon correct authentication.

In order to make it work, I have tried to modify Web.xml to allow form authentication with the built-in "j_security_check" servlet. Upon logging in, it will greet the user "Hello, !" with a simple function *<% request.getRemoteUser() %>* or *<% request.getUserPrincipal().getName() %>*.

Based on the [examples found here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/Security5.html), I modified my Web.xml details as below:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/protected/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/protected/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
        <role-name>users</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <description>Administrator</description>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <description>Users</description>
    <role-name>users</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Under my login.jsp, I have a simple form that does the logging in.

```
<form action="j_security_check" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="j_username">
    Password: <input type="password" name="j_password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Under my index.jsp, it greets the users with a simple request.

```
<body>
    Hello, <% request.getRemoteUser(); %>
    Hello, <% request.getUserPrincipal().getName(); %>
</body>
```

I am facing three issues here. Importance ranked as it is.

1) Error 403
The redirecting and logging in page works. When I try to access index.jsp, I am redirected to login.jsp. When I enter an incorrect uid:pwd pair, I am greeted with error.jsp. When I log in correctly, I am redirected back to index.jsp but I am greeted with an *Error 403: The Website requires you to log in*. I am sure I have logged in because I am previously unable to access the built-in *snoop* page, but after logging in, I can. I suspect it is some settings in my Web.xml

2) Getting the user's ID
Even upon disabling all protection in the Web.xml and accessing the index.jsp, I am greeted with a "*Hello, null!*" instead of "*Hello, user!*". The codes as shown in the index.jsp should be correct as I copied it out from snoop sample codes found on the internet. *request.getRemoteUser()* does not work on my index.jsp but works on the snoop page. There must be something I am not calling before performing the request?

3) Security (not important, yet)
I think this j_security_check is under Spring Security. I am trying to encrypt both the sending and the receiving side as well as the transport channel. This is because for authentication, I believe the password must not be sent or stored in clear text. I found [some information here](http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/java_app/tomcat6/tomcat6_security.htm) which led me to attempt/try to protect this process of authentication.

I would appreciate some guidance and help with regards to the top 3 issues I am facing. It feels like I am close to getting the thing done but it's so close, yet so far...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering, the problem was easily solved with configurations.

1) Assigning roles of Admin and User in Web.xml, one must go into Websphere > .war > Roles and Users > and physically assign the Admin and User roles to roles as specified in Active Directory. This will enable the user to access the page.

2) Also with the Websphere configuration under SPNEGO Configurations, one must append to the list "|" to enable it so that request. Thereafter, authenticated users in the domain will access the item straight away, while external users will be redirected to a login page. The request.getPrincipalUser() now works.

3) There is a Spring Security sample that works. The only problem is that it accesses a local Authentication-Provider in its ApplicationContextSecurity.xml instead of the Active Directory. To protect the channel, under `<transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>`, the NONE should be replaced with CONFIDENTIAL.